# Smooth scroll function getting stuck in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

The smooth scrolling function on my page appears to be getting stuck after a navigation link is clicked and has scrolled to target:

http://www.samnorris.net/portfolio-ss/

in Chrome the mouse scroll seems to be getting stuck for about 2-3 seconds before it releases for some odd reason. Works fine in Firefox.

This is my code:

```
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Scroll Functions
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if($(window).scrollTop()!=0){
    calculatepositionmenu();
};

$(window).on('scroll',function(){

    //Top menu
    calculatepositionmenu();

    //select menu section
    $("body section").each(function (index) {
        if($(this).isOnScreen()){
            $('#mainMenu a').removeClass('select');
            $('#mainMenu a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('select');
        }
    });
});


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main menu scroll to
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$("#mainMenu a,#mainheader a").on('click', function() {
    $("#menu-container").removeClass('open');
    if($(this).data("scrollto")){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).data("scrollto")).offset().top
        }, 1200);
        return false;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menuWrapper">
<section id="menu-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="mainMenu">
            <!-- Site logo-->
            <a class="menulogo logo" href="#" data-scrollto="#mainheader">
                <img alt="Sam Norris - Online Portfolio" src="$ThemeDir/img/menu-logo.png"></a>
            <nav>
                <!-- Principal menu -->
                <a href="#" data-scrollto="#about">The Man</a>
                <a href="#" data-scrollto="#services">The Plan</a>
                <a href="#" data-scrollto="#work">My Work</a>
                <a href="#" data-scrollto="#process">My Process</a>
                <a href="#" data-scrollto="#contact">Contact</a>
                <a href="#" data-scrollto="#blog">Blog</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is flagging your main javascript file at http://www.samnorris.net/portfolio-ss/themes/portfolio/js/main.js as containing malicious code and thus returning it as either 403 / 404 - thus the scripts on your site are not loading.

Take a look at the console window of your browser. Here is a screenshot of it:[image: screesnhot]

The solution is to either change the server settings yourself or contact your host.

Comment: Ah, whoops - had a typographic error in my HTML throwing off the scripts being loaded properly. Have fixed. It's not related to the scrolling issue however.